# Do i need to use separate samsung kies for below android 4.3 and above 4.3?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, automation, appium

I would need to use SeeTest automation tool with android and IOS devices.I heard that we need to install Kies and Itunes for build deployment.
I verifed in samsung sites it is saying **Kies**
Supported model : Feature phone, Smart Phone/Tablet before Galaxy Note III (including Galaxy S4, Note II, etc) and Kies3
Supported model : Smart Phone/Tablet from Galaxy Note III (Android OS 4.3 or over)

Do i need to use separate Samsung kies for below android 4.3 and above 4.3 devices?

or Kies 3 will support all the OS versions?

Comment: Kies3 - Smart Phone/Tablet from Galaxy Note III (Android OS 4.3 or over) so not required a separate kies for android 4.3 and above... http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Comment: @KingofMasses Yes.But my question is Do i need to use separate kies for  below android 4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Samsung specifies you use [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/#none) for android version below 4.3. Download Kies3 for versions above 4.3. Although in some cases after you download Kies, it asks you to download SmartSwitch to transfer (i.e. Back up, restore) data from one device to another. Personally, I prefer WonderShare Mobile Trans which has no issues and works pretty well. You're in a win-win situation when you get the cracked version of it. Hope it helps.
Regards,
SilentAssasian. :)